# How do I fix a value member not found error in iOS foundation with swift while working with notifications?

Tags: swiftui, notifications, foundation

I'm trying to experiment with iOS notifications, so I tried making a swiftUI view that would send a notification, basing it off a tutorial [Found Here](https://blckbirds.com/post/local-notifications-swiftui). I have wrote this so far:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

class LocalNotificationManager: ObservableObject {
    var notifications = [Notification]()
    
    init() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound])
        { granted, error in
            if granted == true && error == nil {
                print("yay")
            } else {
                print("boo")
            }
            
            }
        func sendNotification(title: String, subtitle: String?, body: String, LaunchIn: Double) {
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = title
            if let subtitle = subtitle {
                content.subtitle = subtitle
            }
            content.body = body
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: LaunchIn, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "demoNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}


struct Screen: View {
    @ObservedObject var NotificationManager = LocalNotificationManager()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
            self.notificationManager.sendNotification(title: "It worked", subtitle: ":D", body: "If you see this text, launching the local notification worked!", launchIn: 5)
        }) {
            Text("Test Notification")
        }
    }
}

struct Screen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Screen()
    }
}
```

Its this line where I get problems:

```
self.notificationManager.sendNotification(title: "It worked", subtitle: ":D", body: "If you see this text, launching the local notification worked!", launchIn: 5)
```

I get an error that says:

```
Value of type 'Screen' has no member 'notificationManager'
```

Comment: Typo. Property names are case sensitive. Your NotificationManager property is defined with a capital N and you’re trying to access it with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@ObservedObject var NotificationManager = LocalNotificationManager()
```

To

```
@StateObject var notificationManager = LocalNotificationManager()
```

Variables are case-sensitive and should start with a lowercase

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/